# Why the time lag on RosCosmos News translations?

Tags: roscosmos

I've followed press releases and news articles from Roscosmos for a number of years. Its particularly useful in tracking the Russian view of joint activities and comparing with NASA information on the same topic. As engines and launch capabilities flow between different space operators in the contemporary space entrepreneurial environment its important to stay informed.

The main RosCosmos News can be found at: http://www.federalspace.ru/102/, and it used to provide (official) english language translations concurrently. Then the translations went away for a long period and were replaced by a notice that "English Language news will be provided again in the future" (or similar).

My Russian skills are a bit rusty (last used in 1981) and rely on more accurate translations; so had to switch to using instant google translations. Despite the huge amount of US federal funds that went into Russian/English translations during the cold war, the google versions of RosCosmos press releases end up somewhat comic.

The official English translations are now back again at http://www.en.federalspace.ru/102/ but sometimes with a huge latency meaning that the google versions are still useful.

One can also fill in gaps from Anatoly Zak at http://www.russianspaceweb.com/ but this is also is a delayed selection of prime items, rather than live.

I know there is much interest on the Russian side for US information - take for example RT covering the ULA press conference recently.

Does someone have insight why English language news from RosCosmos is so retarded? Is it political, financial or bureaucratic?

Comment: Last I heard Russian rockets were not fitted with cameras, either.

Comment: Do you by chance happen to have comparable insights into the time lag of official russian translations of NASA news items? :-)